# How to infer the Quarter from a datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dates, which I am trying to infer the Quarter from. I've brute forced a solution, but I want to be able to calculate the quarter from the date to ensure the datas integrity.

The first row will always be the last day of a quarter, and be the 0th quarter. After that, the quarters should repeat three times before incrementing. For example, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.

I've attached the brute force solution below, but does anyone know of an elegant solution of achieving this? Or know of a date time formula that I can applied to use the start/current date to resolve to a quarter number?

```
quarters = [0]
for n in xrange(1, len(date_range)):
    for i in xrange(3):
        quarters.append(n)
quarters = quarters[:len(date_range)]

launchpoint_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31')
date_range = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [pd.to_datetime('2017-03-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-04-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-05-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-06-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-07-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-08-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-09-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-10-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-11-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-01-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-02-28'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-03-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-04-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-05-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-06-30'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-07-31'),
                                     pd.to_datetime('2018-08-31')],
                          'Month': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]})

launchpoint_date = launchpoint_date.month
date_range['Quarter'] = quarters

date_range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Grouper` with `frequency quarter` and `ngroup` i.e

```
date_range['new'] = date_range.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='q')]).ngroup()
```

Output :

```
         Date  Month  Quarter  new
0  2017-03-31      0        0    0
1  2017-04-30      1        1    1
2  2017-05-31      2        1    1
3  2017-06-30      3        1    1
4  2017-07-31      4        2    2
5  2017-08-31      5        2    2
6  2017-09-30      6        2    2
7  2017-10-31      7        3    3
8  2017-11-30      8        3    3
9  2017-12-31      9        3    3
10 2018-01-31     10        4    4
11 2018-02-28     11        4    4
12 2018-03-31     12        4    4
13 2018-04-30     13        5    5
14 2018-05-31     14        5    5
15 2018-06-30     15        5    5
16 2018-07-31     16        6    6
17 2018-08-31     17        6    6
```

Answer (score 2):

With the datetime accessors `.dt` you can extract any individual element:  year, week, hour, etc.

```
( ( date_range['Date'].dt.quarter -    1 ) +
  ( date_range['Date'].dt.year    - 2017 ) * 4 )
```

Results:

```
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    4
11    4
12    4
13    5
14    5
15    5
16    6
17    6
```